# What if you want name collision for Angular InjectionToken?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, module, interface, collision-detection

### Goal

I want to write a feature module that consumes a service. This feature module should not be concerned with the implementation of this service, but rather expect that it implement an interface and that's it.

### Caveats and Corollaries

**Caveat:** The interface that the service should implement will not be defined by this module.

**Corollary:** Where should this interface be defined?

### No provider for InjectionToken

The feature module is meant to be used in many applications across our organization. Each is able to implement the interface for the required service in a different way. If a new use case presents itself, the interface may change and prompt changes to the feature module.

The design that we settled on placed this interface into a shared library.

[This article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html) shows that using an `InjectionToken` causes the following error 'NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ...`

I've created a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-injection-token-copy) that illustrates the above setup and issue.

### Research

The [above thoughtram article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html) describes how `OpaqueToken` was designed to prevent accidental collision of these strings. Adding that, later `InjectionToken` wrapped the `OpaqueToken` to add additional typescript support.

I would like the typescript support for me and my team, but with a token that allows controlled collision.

### Minimum Reproducible Example

See this StackBlitz [Controlled Collision Token](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-controlled-collision-token)

### Sub-optimal Solution

The above example can be fixed if the `InjectionToken` is replaced with a string.

Change the following two (identical files) as such

- /app/external-feature/lib/shared/i-shared.service.ts
- /app/internal-adapter/shared/i-shared.service.ts

```
export const I_SHARED_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<ISharedService>('i-shared-service.shared');
=> 
export const I_SHARED_SERVICE = 'i-shared-service.shared';
```

The result is a loss of typescript support. This seems like a step backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a village to raise a child or to come up with a good architecture.

After discussion with my coworker I've realized that an interface module (a separate npm package) solves the problem.

### Result

The result is that I've got my consuming projects, my feature project and the interface project.

**consuming project**: provides adapter between feature module and internal consumer, providing interface project's `InjectionToken`.

**feature project**: provides feature components and consumes interface project's `InjectionToken`.

**interface project** provides interfaces corresponding `InjectionToken`s